# Magento 2.2.2 How to add external script in Design Layout update XML?

Tags: magento2, xml, layout-update

What is the equivalent to the bellow code for Magento 2.2.2

This work for magento 1.9.2.7 :

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="pixel">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<!-- Custom Stuff Goes here like meta tags js script tags and css links -->]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

What is the equivalent of Magento 2.2.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can add XML file in your theme :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourCustomTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

</head>
</page>
```

Comment: is that not working for you ?

Comment: I am not sure if you understood the question. I need to add this in the admin, per page in the **Design Layout update XML** field?

Comment: If you need your changes in all page than you can add Magento_Theme. Have you tried above code??